# why autocomplete does not work with JSON and SPRING MVC

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

I am puzzled why autocomplete does not work. Here is the  form in the .jsp code below:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save.html" modelAttribute="word">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>German word</th>
            <td><form:input path="german" id="german" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</form:form>
```

here are the javascript functions (in the same .jsp file)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$( "#german" ).autocomplete({
    source: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/get_word_list.html'
});
```

});

and here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
@Autowired
private WordService wordService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/goToDictionary", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {

    Word word = new Word();
    return new ModelAndView("dictionary", "word", word);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get_word_list", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody
List<String> getCountryList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
    System.out.println(query);
    return getMatch(query);
}

public List<String> getMatch(String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Word v : wordService.getAllWord()) {
        if (v.getGerman().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
            matched.add(v.getGerman());
        }
    }
    return matched;
}
```

I know for sure that the getMatch(String query) gets called and works properly.
So I guess the problem is on the jsp. file

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution. it is in the spring-servlet.xml file. It did not work because i failed to add this.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="ttp://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

I added, and now everything is OK

Answer (score 0):

[For JSON to fill the list]
Maybe you should look at the `produces` property of the `@RequestMapping` annotation. It takes a String[] as value. Available since Spring 3.1.x version. I currently use the 3.1.2 and I can get some `application/json` without any problem.

And of course you should add the produces in the data provider of your country list.

[For JavaScript to fill the list]
Maybe the part ${pageContext. request. contextPath} is not evaluated correctly. Did you check inside the produced code of your JSP e.g. with Firebug.

Comment: I found an example on viralpatel blog. Although the example is not accurate, I still managed the follow the tutorial, and autocomplet works. Now I wanted to apply the tutorial to my application and it stopped working. What is even more strange when I copypasted the content of the tutorial to my app, it stopped working. So the code that was running as a stand alone application stopped working as a part of my application. as for the last part of your suggestion ${pageContext. request. contextPath} I am quite convinced that it is true,although I have not peeked inside. (I use Google chrom)